# View in Dialog too small, cutting off text

Tags: android, android-dialog

I've created a dialog in which the view in which the text is displayed seems to be smaller than the dialog, causing the text to be cut off.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
String result = "This is line 1 11111111111111111111111\n" + "This is line 2 22222222222222222\n" + "This is line 3 3333333333333333333333\n" +
    "This is line 4 44444444444444444444444\n" + "This is line 5 55555555555555555\n" + "This is line 6 6666666666666666666666\n" +
    "This is line 7 77777777777777777777777\n" + "This is line 8 88888888888888888\n" + "This is line 9 9999999999999999999999\n" +
    "This is line 1010101010101010101010101\n" + "This is line 11 1111111111111111\n" + "This is line 12 1212121212121212121212\n";

Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
int displayHeight = display.getHeight();

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder. setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    }
                }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
builder.setMessage(result);
Dialog dialog = builder.setView(new View(mContext)).create(); 
dialog.setTitle("Details");

dialog.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
layoutParams.width = displayWidth - 50;
layoutParams.height = displayHeight - 100;

// change position of window on screen
layoutParams.x = displayWidth / 2;     
layoutParams.y = (displayHeight / 2);  

layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.7f; //change this value for more or less dimming

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

dialog.getWindow().addFlags (
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from the added custom view that you implemented in your alertDialog

```
setView(new View(mContext))
```

What will happen is that it will have a space where the view will be placed resulting to the inline message to be cut off since it is long.

just remove it or create an xml layout where you set it as a custom view for the alertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder. setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                }
            }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

    builder.setView(//your xml view here);

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    TextView message = dialog.findViewById(//the id of the textview);
    message.setText(result);

    dialog.setTitle("Details");

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify the dimensions (as I do in my current code) with this solution?

Comment: Another issue: when I do `builder.setView(R.layout.my_textview);` it gives an error saying that at least API level 21 is required. My minimum is level 17.

Comment: @AlLelopath you can use setContentView() for lower level API

Comment: `buillder.setContentView()` gives compile error: Cannot resolve method

Comment: and message is assigned null in `android.view.View message = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_result);`

Comment: I've found its easiest just to skip the xml and use `Dialog dialog = builder.create();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you doing with that code (seems like random lines of codes), but for sure that code would work as expected:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    } 
                }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
builder.setMessage(result);
builder.setTilte("Details");
builder.create().show();
```